# How to set up robots.txt file for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

[UPDATE 2013]

I can't find an authoritative page with a format for robots.txt file for WordPress. I promise to maintain one on my site but I want one here on stack overflow.

If you know what your doing please check current draft here:

http://mast3rpee.tk/?p=127

Everyone else comment on this:

### robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-content/cache/
Disallow: /wp-content/themes/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /comments/
Sitemap: http://domain.com/sitemap.xml
Crawl-delay: 4
```

Comment: There's a stack exchange specifically for WordPress - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=robots.txt

Comment: I thought we were supposed to keep answers here as well?

Comment: You can (until someone moves it). Was just saying that on their boards they have more Wordpress specialists. I didn't know about it until I had a problem with WordPress myself a few weeks ago.

Comment: Same question now on Wordpress SE: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/102561

Answer (score 10):

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /wp-includes
Disallow: /wp-content
Disallow: /e/
Disallow: /show-error-*
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /comment-page-
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Allow: /

User-agent: Adsbot-Google
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Allow: /

Sitemap: http://yoursite.com/sitemap.xml
```

I think this code is very authentic for robots.txt file, Just go to Public_HTML and create file with robots.txt and paste above code.
You can make in your Notepad, just copy above code and paste into notpad but remember file name should robots.txt and upload to your public_HTML.

Comment: I've had issues with using * in robots.txt files. Even though google and bing support it. Some search engines like baidu are still iffy in their support. Also I discovered that you MUST close your disallow tags with a trailing /. If not you can have issues with google and can even get your site removed from bing. (ie instead of disallow: /wp-content you should use disallow: /wp-content/)

Answer (score 1):

As with all things SEO, things change. I think that the current advice is to have a a very minimal robots.txt file.

Ignoring wp-admin, wp-includes, wp-content, etc. may prevent Google from rendering pages correctly, which it doesn't like.

Check out this article by Yoast: https://yoast.com/wordpress-robots-txt-example/.

Answer (score 0):

Create in notepad robots.txt and upload it to public_html in CPANEL .

*remember rename your file notepad to robots before you upload it to public_html

Comment: Dear Muhammad. This will not work. Consider 000webhost which disables text files by default as a "Security Precaution"

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to block much in your `robots.txt` nowadays single Google tries to load all assets to determine "mobile friendliness." At minimum you can block /wp-admin. Here's [a more detailed, current answer to the question at the StackExchange forum for WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5256/what-is-a-good-robots-txt/182407#182407).